# How to send thumbnail for video with youtube data api v3

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api, video-thumbnails

I upload the video with youtube data api . I use python . this project is working I can upload video with api but I can't upload thumbnails for video . I did search in google for this issue . I did'nt find any idea . I asked to chat gpt , chat gpt is said there isn't any way for this event , just you can choice the thumbnail in youtube studio . can you have any idea .

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from argparse import Namespace
import httplib2
import os
import random
import sys
import time

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow

coverimages_folder = "coverimages"
image_files = os.listdir(coverimages_folder)
selected_image = random.choice(image_files)
image_path = os.path.join(coverimages_folder, selected_image)

# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError)

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]

# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google API Console at
# https://console.cloud.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
# authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the API Console
https://console.cloud.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ("public", "private", "unlisted")

def upload_video_to_yt(video_file: str, title: str, description: str, tags: list):
    if not os.path.exists(video_file):
        print("Couldn't find file:", video_file)
        exit(1)

    information = Namespace(
        auth_host_name="localhost",
        noauth_local_webserver=False,
        auth_host_port=[8080, 8090],
        logging_level="INFO",
        file=video_file,
        title=title,
        description=description,
        category="24",
        keywords=tags,      
        privacyStatus="public",
    )

    youtube = get_authenticated_service(information)
    try:
        initialize_upload(youtube, information)
    except HttpError as e:
        print("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
    else:
        print(f"LETS GO! FILE {video_file} IS NOW UPLOADED AS \"{title}\"!")


def get_authenticated_service(args):
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
                                   scope=YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE,
                                   message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

    storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
    credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

    return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
                 http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
    tags = None
    if options.keywords:
        tags = options.keywords.split(",")
    thumbnail_upload = MediaFileUpload(image_path, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)

    body = dict(
        snippet=dict(
            title=options.title,
            description=options.description,
            tags=tags,
            categoryId=options.category
        ),
        status=dict(
            privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
        )
    )

    # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
        part=",".join(body.keys()),
        body=body,
        media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
    )


    resumable_upload(insert_request)

# This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
# failed upload.


def resumable_upload(insert_request):
    response = None
    error = None
    retry = 0
    while response is None:
        try:
            print("Uploading file...")
            status, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
            if response is not None:
                if 'id' in response:
                    print("Video id '%s' was successfully uploaded." %
                          response['id'])
                else:
                    exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)
        except HttpError as e:
            if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
                error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status,
                                                                     e.content)
            else:
                raise
        except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS as e:
            error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e

        if error is not None:
            print(error)
            retry += 1
            if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
                exit("No longer attempting to retry.")

            max_sleep = 2 ** retry
            sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
            print("Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % sleep_seconds)
            time.sleep(sleep_seconds)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    argparser.add_argument("--file", required=True,
                           help="Video file to upload")
    argparser.add_argument("--title", help="Video title", default="Test Title")
    argparser.add_argument("--description", help="Video description",
                           default="Test Description")
    argparser.add_argument("--category", default="22",
                           help="Numeric video category. " +
                           "See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list")
    argparser.add_argument("--keywords", help="Video keywords, comma separated",
                           default="")
    argparser.add_argument("--privacyStatus", choices=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES,
                           default=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES[0], help="Video privacy status.")
    args = argparser.parse_args()

    if not os.path.exists(args.file):
        exit("Please specify a valid file using the --file= parameter.")

    youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
    try:
        initialize_upload(youtube, args)
    except HttpError as e:
        print("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```

I use upload*video*yt function for uplaod video

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).